# Title: How to handle PDF files get a specific element location in Appium WebDriverIO?

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I am working on a WebDriverIO project and need to handle PDF files. I would like to know how I can find specific element locations from a PDF using WebDriverIO. Can someone provide guidance or code examples on how to achieve this?

Here's what I have tried so far:
`let els1 = await driver.$$("//android.widget.Button[@index=3]"); await els1[0].click(); let els2 = await driver.$$("//android.view.View[@content-desc=\"Signature\"]"); await els2[0].click(); let els3 = await driver.$$("//android.widget.ImageView[@index=1]"); await els3[0].click(); await screen.touchAction({ action: 'tap', x: 100, y:200 }) await screen.touchAction([ 'press', { action: 'moveTo', x: 200, y: 300 }, 'release' ])`

However, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or if there's a better approach. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I'm specifically looking for solutions using WebDriverIO and JavaScript.